# Do stop orders work in overnight trading

Tags: trading

I directed my broker to place a 5% stop order on a stock in my portfolio selling in excess of $100/share. Some weeks later while still holding the stock the price dropped 30% in overnight trading. The 5% stop order did not execute. Can you explain why. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Stop orders and complex orders like  all-or-none order  do not execute in extended sessions though you can place limit orders, assuming that you have account approval to trade during the extended sessions.

In your situation, the order would not execute until the next trading day, assuming that shares opened below your 5% stop price.